# how to read numbers that separated with dot?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I'm trying to read such log file:

```
14:27:30:000 1.01628432 152.35 310794
14:27:35:000 1.01628432 152.35 310794
14:27:36:000 1.01628432 152.35 310794
14:27:37:000 1.01628432 152.35 310794
14:27:38:000 1.01628432 152.35 310794
14:27:39:000 1.01628432 152.35 310794
```

using such code:

```
data = textscan(fLog, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f.%f %f.%f %f');
```

And it can not be read completely. At the same time if I use `,` as separator in numbers instead of `.` everything works fine with such code:

```
data = textscan(fLog, '%f:%f:%f:%f %f,%f %f,%f %f');
```

I guess probably `.` is special charachter os something. As I can not change file that I need to read to use `,` I need to adjust my matlab script to accept `.`. The question is how to do that.

Comment: To clarify, you want the number `152.35` to be read in as two fields, `152` and `35`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is a part of a floating point number (`%f`), if you're sure you want to read each number individually, read them as integers (`%d`):

```
'%f:%f:%f:%f %d.%d %d.%d %f'
```

Are you sure you don't want to read field 2 and 3 as floats:

```
'%f:%f:%f:%f %f %f %f'
```